# My custom viewcontroller is not being called after app finished launching

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my Mac app, I have a default GNAppDelegate and a custom GNViewController. The GNMainViewController will set one of two NSButtons to inactive after app finished launching(using the method `setButtonStatus`). However in my situation, the  GNMainViewController's `setButtonStatus` is not run after app finished launching. If I click one button, then the application starts to work as expected.

In my GNAppDelegate,

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self.mainViewController setButtonStatus];
    NSLog(@"Appdelegate launched successful");
}
```

In my GNMainViewController,

```
- (void) setButtonStatus
{
    /* Some code here that I edited away for this post */  
}
```

What is the reason that the first call by GNAppDelegate is not run?

**Update:**

I added a log statement right after the setButtonStatus is called. This logging statement is run, so the statement before it must also have run. My GNMainViewController's setButtonStatus method is also correct because I can click on buttons to execute this action. It's just the first call by the appdelegate that is not run(or not producing expected result).

**Update 2**

I tried adding initialisation here also not working out.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.mainViewController = [[GNMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
    [self.mainViewController setButtonStatus];
    NSLog(@"App finished launching");
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show where you are initializing mainviewcontroller ? It looks like its nil in app did finish launching

Comment: I @synthesize it in the AppDelegate.

Comment: By synthesize do you mean to say that you have never initialized using `alloc initWithNibName` ? Could you please post that code here ?

Comment: I tried adding initialisation here but also not working out.

Answer (score 0):

At applicationDidFinishLaunching it doesn't mean that your mainViewController is created/ ready to call setButtonStatus event.
I think that you should add setButtonStatus to viewDidLoad from mainViewController.

Comment: Where do you find viewDidLoad when you develop a Mac OS X application?

Comment: viewDidLoad is for iOS development, not Mac OS X application.

Comment: sorry about that ios dev :) 
You can use - (void)awakeFromNib or - (void)loadView

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/loadView

Answer (score 0):

The answer is enter the code in `-loadView` rather than `-applicationDidFinishedLaunching`. The sequence of events is that the NIB file will be loaded after `-applicationDidFinishedLaunching`, hence overwritten what I have set programatically.